# How to recover accidentally deleted iPhone app data?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, data-recovery

I did something stupid and am hoping there is a fix:  I deleted an app on my iPhone (Fyuse) and reinstalled it because it was crashing a lot, in hopes this would fix the crashing issue.  I neglected to realize that I was deleting all the app data -- this included about 20GB of media that was stored locally.  I would really love to have all that media back, but I fear there is no way possible now to recover it.

I am hoping that in a low-level on the phone the data has not actually been wiped yet because it hasn't been overwritten (I just did this, haven't restarted yet).  Is it possible to recover this data?  If so, what is the easiest/best/cheapest way?

I've searched around and there are a lot of [programs out there](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-recover-lost-data-or-restore-deleted-data-from-an-iPhone) advertising/claiming to do something like this, but they all look super sketchy and I was hoping for input from someone with experience in this who can actually confirm a working solution.

No I don't have a hard backup on iTunes from anytime recently (my bad, I know), and this app data was not backed up on iCloud (way over the free 5GB limit).  So recovery would have to be like an "undo" button, assuming it has not been overwritten in the phone's flash storage.  iPhone 6s Plus running iOS 10.3.

Comment: There was a warning. When you delete an app, it says: "Deleting this app will also delete its data." And no, there is no way to get it back without a backup. Your phone's storage is encrypted, and any data deleted is lost forever.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I think that is in smaller text below "are you sure you want to delete...".  I will edit the above to reflect.  Also, that is sad :( Shame on me for not having hard backups of this device.